# Get array from 1 to number of columns of csv in nextflow

Tags: nextflow

One of my process gives output of one csv file. I want to create an array channel from 1 to number of columns. For example:
My output

```
my_out_ch.view() -> test.csv
```

Assume, test.csv has 11 columns. Now I want to create a channel which gives me:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,910,11
```

How could I get this? I have tried with `splitText` operator as below without luck:

```
my_out_ch.splitText(by:1,limit:1)
```

But it only gives me the columns names. There is a parameter `elem`, I am not sure if `elem` could give me the array and also not sure how to use it. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [splitCsv](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#splitcsv) operator to parse the CSV file. Then create an [intRange](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/IntRange.html) using the [map](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#map) operator. Either call `collect()` to emit a `java.util.ArrayList` or call `join()` to emit a string. For example:

```
params.input_tsv = 'test.tsv'

Channel.fromPath( params.input_tsv )
    | splitCsv( sep: '\t', limit: 1 )
    | map { (1..it.size()).join(',') }
    | view()
```

Results:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
```